# Morphisms/functors of lower categories to Higher Categories

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

It it possible for there to be a morphism/functor that makes a lower category become a higher category. And if so, can this work for all categories?

Comment: What do you mean by "higher category"? There are various definitions.

Comment: There are higher dimensional categories apart from the usual 1-category. Such as the $\infty$-Category a 2- category and so on.